# How to show the function is onto here according to the constraints?

Tags: functions

> Let $f:(0, \infty) \longrightarrow(0, \infty)$ be a function which is continuous and $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x>0$. If $f$ is not the identity function, prove that $f$ must be strictly decreasing.
> I tried proving $f(x)$ is bijective which is needed as follows : for one-one lets consider f(x_1) = $f(x_2)$ for $x_1$ not equal to $x_2$ , then considering $f(f(x_1))$ = $x_1$, $f(f(x_2)$ = $x_2$ . We get $f(f(x_1))$ = $f(f(x_2)) = x_2$ , implying $x_1= x_2$ contradiction, but i am not getting how to prove its onto too ? How to show that its codomain = range ?

Comment: The condition $f(f(x))=x$ makes it obvious, no?

Comment: Oh i see as x can vary from 0 to infinity hence f(f(x)) top varies in that range hence f(x) is onto right ? @DavidMitra

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Okay got it thanks @DavidMitra